# Get the schema name of the stored procedure of any database

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, I have this database query which works fine if it runs under the database to which the stored procedure belongs

```
SELECT sys.objects.name, sys.schemas.name AS schema_name
FROM sys.objects 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id 
WHERE sys.objects.name = 'usp_gallery_delete'
```

What I am trying to do is, irrespective of any database I am in, if I execute the passed stored procedure name, I should be able to get the schema name of that stored procedure and also should be able to get the definition of that stored procedure.

Comment: What if there are multiple databases with exactly the same schema and exactly the same stored procedure name? There is no requirement (or possibility) to enforce uniqueness between databases. In any case, if you want to work across databases, you won't be able to get around writing a loop with `USE`, or constructing dynamic SQL (`<database>.sys.objects`), based on what's in `sys.databases`. The (undocumented) `sp_msforeachdb` built-in stored procedure can be done to do this in a quick and dirty manner, but that should only be done for one-offs and ideally not production code.

Comment: Look at the code of `sp_msforeachdb` and adapt it just for your case

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `UNION ALL` query which will select from every single database

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  o.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS name,
  s.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS schema_name
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.objects o
INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE o.name = ''usp_gallery_delete''
'  AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
'  )

FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.database_id > 4;  -- not system DB


EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to quote the injected database name, and note the use of short meaningful table aliases.

Comment: got this error `Msg 451, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT statement column 2.` @charlieface

Comment: Then different databases must have different default collations. You can add a `COLLATE` clause, see edit